# How to set allow all for guest in Mconf-bigbluebutton

Tags: bigbluebutton

How can I set option for default allow for guest users in Mconf-bigbluebutton?
As I want to set default entry option for guest also. There should not be any guest management window on moderator side. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution. I have just changed default guest policy to ALWAYS_ACCEPT in this file

> bigbluebutton-apps/src/main/scala/org/bigbluebutton/core/api/MeetingActor.scala

Code change :

```
var guestPolicy = GuestPolicy.ALWAYS_ACCEPT
```

Now, it will not ask for moderator waiting to guest.